# Change slide direction - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change slide direction for my menu. Is there a way I can make slide from left direction ? Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_trigger").on("click", function() {
      $(".fixed_top_menu").animate({
        left: "0px",
        display: "block"
      }).slideToggle(120)
    })
  }) 
< /script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use slideToggle, you can use animate or slide instead. This is done by someone else.

```
(http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/light/ )
```